# Opencart update modifications folder files

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I'm newbie to opencart, i changed some controllers and models in `system/storage/modifications` folder.

In opencart admin side when i install new extensions and then goto `modifications >> clear cache`, the files i changed in `system/storage/modifications` gets overwrite

can anyone suggest how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not edit the files in `storage/modification` folder, because as soon as you hit the refresh button in extensions / modifications in admin panel, OpenCart removes them all and creates the new files.

You can use:

**[Modification System](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/wiki/Modification-System)**

**[vQmod](http://docs.opencart.com/en-gb/administration/vqmod/)**

[**Event System**](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/wiki/Events-System)